# Class variables VS constants in Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application there can be only one current Event which defaults to the nearest date event. I need to retrieve this event in various places and since it doesn't change it makes sense to cache it. There are two ways of doing it known to me:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  CURRENT_EVENT = Event.where('starts_on >= ?', Time.now).
                  order('starts_on ASC').limit(1).first

  # OR

  def self.current_event
    @@current_event ||= Event.where('starts_on >= ?', Time.now).
                      order('starts_on ASC').limit(1).first
  end

end
```

Which one would be the best? Or any other alternatives? I know that using @@ class variables is not recommended since they are not thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you aren't right about your approach: this way your app will keep your cached value forever. New `events` won't affect it which is completely wrong. It may be the situation when some event already passed but it is still cached as "current".

By the way: `limit(1).first` does the same as the only `first`.

Answer (score 1):

Neither first nor second approach are correct. If you define constant - it will find Event, actual on Rails initialization process time. Second approach will not `cache` your record.
As for me, this is not so **fat** data to cache.